# Что такое невалидный код?

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, что значит **невалидный код** и **валидный код**? Большое спасибо!

Comment: невалидный - не работающий, валидный - работающий))

Comment: правильнее читать вАлидный или валИдный код?

Comment: С этими вопросами лучше [сюда](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) А вообще http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9&all=x

Comment: https://www.imagecms.net/blog/obzory/validnost-koda-chto-eto-i-kak-ee-proverit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Невалидный код* - смысле ***No valid code***. *Valid* с английского **действительный**. Аналогично невалидный - ***невалидный код*** т.е. не действительный.